# Firestore cloud functions not triggering without deploying functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Can I use firestore triggers without first deploying my functions? I am getting an error that looks like it but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Firestore trigger to respond to a change in a document that's actually in Firestore (and not running in a local emulator), then yes, you will have to deploy the trigger.  Cloud Functions only works when deployed to Google's cloud.

Comment: Thank you, Doug. It's my first time using Firestore so my questions might sound somewhat annoying so please forgive me. Is there a way for me to make everything work in my local emulator? I tried deploying but I was asked to upgrade to a paid plan before I can do that.

Comment: If you have a new question about the emulator, please post your question separately.  Be sure to follow the documentation.